# Map same table to two different lists

Tags: c#, xml, hibernate, nhibernate, orm

Is it possible to have 1 table that maps to two different lists?

for example 1 list might hold all the Active Orders and the other list might hold all the Submitted Orders.

In the database the orders are in 1 table with a different state.

I am assuming you can use the where clause on the bag collections? But will I have any issues when persisting data?

Comment: I guess it is not a mapping issue, and it is a way you do a query to get your orders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should handle this on the mapping level. Either query the filtered data in a service, or add methods to your entity, like `getActiveOrders()` and `getSubmittedOrders()` which would just filter the (mapped) list of all orders.

BTW, I think where clause on collection mappings would work.

Comment: Your solution is what I had to begin with but I was concerned about performance because now all orders will need to be retrieved in order to perform the filters within the aggregate root. 

This made me think that maybe my Aggregate was too big!

Comment: Did you try `@Where` on your collections?

Comment: Where works perfectly for reading but I guess I was concerned with retrieving the whole list in order to add a new order.

Comment: I think the only tricky thing would be when you change thw status so the order goes from one collection to another. If that works, probably everything else would also work. It shouldn't be too much work to cover these scenarios with tests.